# How to make a .NET Core app on MacOS scriptable (with Applescript)?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, applescript

Straight to the question:
**How to make a simple .NET Core console application scriptable with Applescript?**

For the sake of the experiment, let's assume that my app looks like below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScriptableCsharpApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; } 
            = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public static int StaticCounter { get; set; } = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running!");

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

            CancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("Shutting Down!");
        }

        private static Response GetFullResponse()
        {
            return new Response()
            {
                Counter = StaticCounter++,
                Message = "Hello from C#!"
            };
        }

        private static string GetMessage()
        {
            StaticCounter++;
            return "Hello from C#!";
        }

        private static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Level 1: How do I make the following script return the Message from GetMessage(), while the app is running:

```
tell application "ScriptableCsharpApp"
 set message to get message 
 return message 
end tell
```

Level 2: How do I make the following script return the Message property of GetFullResponse's result, while the app is running:

```
tell application "ScriptableCsharpApp"
 set response to get full response
 set message to message of response
 return message 
end tell
```

**EDIT**
A comment claims that there's not enough info. I'm confused, but ok, let's be VERY verbose here:

- on Windows, install .NET Core 3.x SDK
- open Visual Studio 2019 on Windows
- File -> New -> Project -> .NET Core Console app (C#)
- copy-paste code from above over Program.cs
- Ctrl+. to resolve missing references (should add a NuGet pkg for the threading stuff)
- zip the solution folder, send it to a Mac, extract somewhere
- on the Mac, install .NET Core 3.x runtime
- in terminal.app, navigate to the solution folder and run "dotnet ScriptableCsharpApp"

Now you have a windowless app that runs until you (x) out of it.

The task is to explain what code changes are required so that I can open AppleScript editor, create a new AppleScript, copy-paste the script mentioned above and run it to get the desired results.

Enough detail?

Comment: Not enough to detail to answer your question buddy.

Comment: Hey - Edited for more detail.

Comment: Without a native macOS event loop I suspect the answer is: you don’t. You can install Apple event handlers via the Foundation framework’s NSAppleEventManager or the old Carbon C APIs, but they still need something to fire them. If you make it a standard CLI executable, AppleScript can run it via Standard Additions’ `do shell script` command (caveat that doesn’t support stdin; use argv and stdout only).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although admittedly I did not understand any of it where you invoke Mac-specific stuff ^^ (I don't know MacOS well and I've never programmed in Swift or Obj-C). But I understand that it's not easy. Ok, got that. How about a native MacOS app written in Obj-C or Swift, deployed alongside my main .NET Core app, whose only purpose would be to call the main app via e.g. grpc? It wouldn't be my app that is scriptable per se, but functionally it would be the same I guess. I suppose however that this should be a whole new question :p

Comment: That would be one way to put an “AppleScriptable” GUI shell around your .NET CLI app. Being ObjC/Swift, it could use NSTask/Process to launch and communicate with the latter. Without knowing what your .NET app does, it’s hard to make any recommendations. Personally I wouldn’t put a lot of effort into AppleScript development right now: it’s old, legacy tech now in maintenance mode and very out of favor. With Apple’s new Shortcuts app looking to land in 10.16, hopefully Apple will provide us a clearer picture of the future of Mac Automation at WWDC later this year.